# "Peer access" failed when using pycuda and tensorflow together

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, gpu, pycuda

I have some codes in python3 like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule, compile
import tensorflow as tf

# create device and context
cudadevice=cuda.Device(gpuid1)
cudacontext=cudadevice.make_context()

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list={}.format(gpuid2)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)



# compile from a .cu file
cuda_mod = SourceModule(cudaCode, include_dirs = [dir_path], no_extern_c = True, options = ['-O0'])
# in the .cu code a texture named "map" is defined as:
# texture<float4, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> map;
texRef = cuda_mod.get_texref('map')

# tex is a np.ndarray with shape 256*256*4, and it is the output of a tensorflow's graph by calling sess.run()
tex = np.ascontiguousarray(tex).astype(np.float32)
tex_gpu = cuda.make_multichannel_2d_array(tex, 'C') 

# error here!!!!!
texRef.set_array(tex_gpu)
```

and the error message:
    `pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuTexRefSetArray failed: peer access has not been enabled`

The peer access error appeared when `tensorflow` is also on use (even if gpuid1 and gpuid2 are same), but everything goes right without `tensorflow`. 
I found that "peer access" has something to do with communicating between GPUs (devices). But what I'm doing here is just setting a `numpy` array to GPU memory as texture, so I think it has nothing to do with transferring data between different GPUs. So what's wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: I would guess you are implicitly trying to share resources between different CUDA contexts held by different processes. That can be made to work, but only via the IPC facilities of the CUDA APIs. Unless you are capable of making significant modifications to the internals of both PyCUDA and Tensorflow, I very much doubt this will ever work as you are trying to

Comment: Thanks talonmies. It seems I have found the solution. When texRef.set_array(tex_gpu) is inserted between cudadevice.cudacontext.push() and cudadevice.cudacontext.pop() to  explicitly switch the cuda context, everything goes okay.

Comment: If that is your solution, please write an answer describing it so that others can benefit from your experience

Answer (score 2):

It seems I have found the solution. When texRef.set_array(tex_gpu) is inserted between cudadevice.cudacontext.push() and cudadevice.cudacontext.pop() to explicitly switch the cuda context, everything goes okay.