# Pycuda: cuTexRefSetArray failed: peer access has not been enabled

Tags: pycuda

Code as below:

```
cuda.init()
dev = cuda.Device(0)
context = dev.make_context()
context.push()
tfG = mod.get_texref("tfG")
tfG.set_array(cuda.np_to_array(Gs.astype(np.float32),order='C'))
context.pop()
```

gives me error message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LogicError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-92ff15f5e108> in <module>()
      1 Gs = np.arange(100).reshape([10,10])
      2 context.push()
----> 3 tfG.set_array(cuda.np_to_array(Gs.astype(np.float32),order='C'))
      4 context.pop()

LogicError: cuTexRefSetArray failed: peer access has not been enabled
```

I read a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980060/peer-access-failed-when-using-pycuda-and-tensorflow-together/48378961#48378961) but didn't solve this erroer

P.S. with auto init, it will works:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
tfG = mod.get_texref("tfG")
Gs = np.arange(100).reshape([10,10])
tfG.set_array(cuda.np_to_array(Gs.astype(np.float32),order='C'))
```

But my problem is that I want to use mpi for my program eventually so I need to figure out why it doesn't work.